# ASP.NET MVC 4 Entity Framework entity to get foreign key field from membership user profile table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-membership, foreign-key-relationship

I have entities in a separate project. One of the entity needs to refer a `UserId` in `UserProfile` model in the `Web` project which is already referencing `Entity` project. Anybody can help to get a new foreign key to my entity (something like `Expense` entity class to get additional field `Expender` which is already a primary key in `UserProfile` which is a membership table?)

```
namespace ExpenseAssistant.Entities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Expense
    /// </summary>
    public class ExpenseEntry
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets Unique Id of the Expense
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets Description about the Expense
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string ExpenseDescription { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Amount Spent
        /// </summary>
        public virtual float Amount { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Expender which is the UserId from UserProfile Table
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
        public virtual int ExpenderId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Membership tables are in the same database in which I have all the entity tables.

I tried with `update-database` in console after adding this key `ExpenderId` in `ExpenseEntry` entity, I am getting the error as below,

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ExpenderId' on type
>   'ExpenseAssistant.Entities.ExpenseEntry' is not valid. The navigation
>   property 'UserProfile' was not found on the dependent type
>   'ExpenseAssistant.Entities.ExpenseEntry'. The Name value should be a
>   valid navigation property name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

The first problem is that the attribute is meant to be used on a navigation property (which you don't seem to have).

**An example of such a navigation property would be:**

```
public virtual UserProfile Expender { get; set; }
```

The second problem is that the name passed to the ForeignKeyAttribute constructor must be the name of the property containing the foreign key in this class, not the name of the table or entity referenced by the foreign key.

**This is what your code should look like:**

```
public virtual int ExpenderId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ExpenderId")]

public virtual UserProfile Expender { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have fixed this in a different way! From the existing tables, using model diagram, I created a relationship. After the reverse engineering , I ran update-database command from console. It Worked! Anyway thanks!